# How can I refactor my service use single responsibility principle?

Tags: java, spring, oop, architecture, single-responsibility-principle

I read "***Clean Code***" book ((c) Robert C. Martin) and try to use **SRP**(single responsibility principle). And I have some questions about it. I have some service in my application, and I do not know how can I refactor it so it matched the right approach. For example, I have service:

```
public interface SendRequestToThirdPartySystemService  {
    void sendRequest();
}
```

What does it do if you look at the class name? - send a request to the third party system.  But I have this implementation:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SendRequestToThirdPartySystemServiceImpl implements SendRequestToThirdPartySystemService {

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topicName;

    private final EventBus eventBus;
    private final ThirdPartyClient thirdPartyClient;
    private final CryptoService cryptoService;
    private final Marshaller marshaller;

    public SendRequestToThirdPartySystemServiceImpl(EventBus eventBus, ThirdPartyClient thirdPartyClient, CryptoService cryptoService, Marshaller marshaller) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        this.thirdPartyClient = thirdPartyClient;
        this.cryptoService = cryptoService;
        this.marshaller = marshaller;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendRequest() {
        try {
            ThirdPartyRequest thirdPartyRequest = createThirdPartyRequest();

            Signature signature = signRequest(thirdPartyRequest);
            thirdPartyRequest.setSignature(signature);

            ThirdPartyResponse response = thirdPartyClient.getResponse(thirdPartyRequest);

            byte[] serialize = SerializationUtils.serialize(response);

            eventBus.sendToQueue(topicName, serialize);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Send request was filed with exception: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

private ThirdPartyRequest createThirdPartyRequest() {
    ...
    return thirdPartyRequest;
}

private Signature signRequest(ThirdPartyRequest thirdPartyRequest) {
    byte[] elementForSignBytes = marshaller.marshal(thirdPartyRequest);
    Element element = cryptoService.signElement(elementForSignBytes);
    Signature signature  = new Signature(element);  
    return signature;
}
```

What does it do actually? - **create a request -> sign this request -> send this request -> to send the response to Queue**

This service inject 4 another services: `eventBus`, `thirdPartyClient`, `cryptoSevice` and `marshaller`. And in **sendRequest** method calls each this service. 
If I want to create a unit test for this service, I need mock 4 services. I think it's too much.

Can somebody indicate how can this service be changed?

Change the class name and leave as is?
Split into several classes?
Something else?

Comment: You can ask this question in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The SRP is a tricky one.

Let's ask two questions:

- *What is a responsibility?*
- *What are the different types of responsibilities?*

One important thing about responsibilities is that they have a ***Scope*** and you can define them in different levels of ***Granularity***. and are hierarchical in nature.

Everything in your application can have a responsibility.

Let's start with ***Modules***. Each module has responsibilities an can adhere to the SRP.

Then this ***Module*** can be made of ***Layers***. Each ***Layer*** has a responsibility and can adhere to the ***SRP***.

Each ***Layer*** is made of different ***Objects***, ***Functions*** etc. Each ***Object*** and/or ***Function*** has responsibilities and can adhere to the SRP.

Each ***Object*** has ***Methods***. Each ***Method*** can adhere to the SRP. Objects can contain other objects and so on.

Each ***Function*** or ***Method*** in an ***Object*** is made of statements and can be broken down to more ***Functions***/***Methods***. Each statement can have responsibilities too.

Let's give an example. Let's say we have a ***Billing*** module. If this module is implemented in a single huge class, does this module adhere to the SRP?

- From the point of view of the system, the module does indeed adhere to the SRP. The fact that it's a mess doesn't affect this fact.
- From the point of view of the module, the class that represents this module doesn't adhere to the SRP as it will do a lot of other things, like communicate with DB, send Emails, do business logic etc.

Let's take a look at the different types of responsibilities.

- *When something should be done*
- *How it should be dome*

Let's take an example.

```
public class UserService_v1 {

    public class SomeOperation(Guid userID) {
        var user = getUserByID(userID);
        // do something with the user
    }

    public User GetUserByID(Guid userID) {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE ID = {userID}";
        var dbResult = db.ExecuteQuery(query);
        return CreateUserFromDBResult(dbResult);
    }

    public User CreateUserFromDBResult(DbResult result) {
        // parse and return User
    }
}

public class UserService_v2 {

    public void SomeOperation(Guid userID) {
        var user = UserRepository.getByID(userID);
        // do something with the user
    }
}
```

Let's take a look at these two implementations.

`UserService_v1` and `UserService_v2` do exactly the same thing but different ways. From the point of view of the ***System***, these services adhere to the SRP as they contain operations related to `Users`.

Now let's take a look at what they actually do to complete their work.

`UserService_v1` does these things:

1. Builds a SQL query string.
2. Calls the `db` to execute the query
3. Takes the specific `DbResult` and creates a `User` from it.
4. Does the operation on the `User`

`UserService_v2` does these things:
1. Requests from the repository the `User` by ID
2. Does the operation on the `User`

`UserService_v1` contains:

- ***How*** *specific query is build*
- ***How*** *the specific `DbResult` is mapped to a User*
- ***When*** *this query need to be called* (in the begging of the operation in this case)

`UserService_v1` contains:

- ***When*** *a `User` should be retrieved from the DB*

`UserRepository` contains:

- ***How*** *specific query is build*
- ***How*** *the specific `DbResult` is mapped to a `User`*

What we do here is to move the responsibility of ***How*** from the `Service` to the `Repository`. This way each class has *one reason to change*. If *how* changes, we change the `Repository`. If *when* changes, we change the `Service`.

This way we create objects that *collaborate with each other* to do specific work, by *dividing responsibilities*. The tricky parts is: *what responsibilities we divide*?

If we have a `UserService` and `OrderService` we don't divide *when* and *how* here. We divide *what* so we can have one service per [Entity](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html) in our system.

It's natural for there services to need other objects to do their work. We can of course add all of the responsibilities of *what*, *when* and *how* to a single object but that just makes to the messy, unreadable and hard to change.

In this regard the SRP helps us to achieve cleaner code by having more smaller parts that *collaborate* with and *use* each other.

Let's take a look at your specific case.

If you can move the responsibility of *how* the `ClientRequest` is created and signed by moving it to the `ThirdPartyClient`, your `SendRequestToThirdPartySystemService` will only tell *when* this request should be sent. This will remove `Marshaller`, and `CryptoService` as dependencies from your `SendRequestToThirdPartySystemService`.

Also you have `SerializationUtils` that you probably rename to `Serializer` to capture the intent better as `Utils` is something that we stick to objects that we just don't know how to name and contains a lot of logic (and probably multiple responsibilities).

This will reduce the number of dependencies and your tests will have less things to mock.

Here's a version of the `sendRequest` method with less responsibilities.

```
@Override
public void sendRequest() {
    try {
        // params are not clear as you don't show them to your code
        ThirdPartyResponse response = thirdPartyClient.sendRequest(param1, param2);

        byte[] serializedMessage = SerializationUtils.serialize(response);

        eventBus.sendToQueue(topicName, serialize);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Send request was filed with exception: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

From your code I'm not sure if you can also move the responsibility of serialization and deserialization to the `EventBus`, but if you can do that, it will remove `Seriazaliation` from your service also. This will make the `EventBus` responsible for *how* it serialized and stores the things inside it making it more cohesive. Other objects that collaborate with it will just tell it to send and object to the queue not caring *how* this objects get's there.